# Is it possible to record an RCA signal with the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: input-device

Does anybody know of a way to record the RCA video output from a security camera with the Raspberry pi?

I know that the Raspberry Pi has an RCA output, but this won't work for recording. Would an RCA to USB adapter be the thing I am looking for?

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is what you are looking for:https://smile.amazon.com/Usb2-0-Capture-Compatible-Window-Black/dp/B00RMYWGWC/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8 or https://www.febon.net/products/usb20-febon100-uvc-cvbs-composite-capture-card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a RCA to USB adapter would work. **But** before buying one email the manufacturer and see if they have Linux support and more specifically do they have Debian Arm drivers. It will be pointless buying an adapter that has no driver.

I have seen people record video from USB cameras though so it is possible.

Comment: If anybody reading this thread finds or knows of an adapter which works for this purpose, please post it here. I will do the same.